# Navigation/Menu displays in Internet Explorer behind the slideshow

Tags: css

I worked on a solution since 2 days but i can´t find the problem.
The Problem is that my Navigation/menu is behind a slideshow in the header and that´s only in IE.
All other Browsers worked fine.

Here is the URL: http://ditzinger.de/wordpress/bahntechnik/

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you use z-index for the header and the slideshow? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

```
In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking context, 
starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore z-index doesn’t work correctly. 

giving the parent element a higher z-index actual fixes the bug.
```

http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Answer (score 0):

Set the higher `z-index` value into your sub-menu class with position.....